# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS: Slow down on localhost after recent update

Tags: networking, localhost, tcp-ip

I have been developing a network enabled application and been testing it on 127.0.0.1 (localhost). The application is completely memory bound, i.e. it never touches the hard disk.

The procedure of test is to connect with the application and then flood it with statically generated data which is echoed back to the source. After predefined volume (Megabytes) of data is echoed back, I measure the time elapsed since the beginning (timer starts after a socket connection is established).

Application can either use a normal TCP socket or an equivalent unix domain socket interchangeably.

Since today morning (Saturday) Indian time the throughput (measured as MB/s of data transferred) of the application running on 127.0.0.1 (localhost) slowed down by a factor of 3.
I haven't made any changes in the application since past 5 days.

- To be 100% sure I repeated the test with the much older versions of the same application (up to 12 months old) and all of them exhibit a slow down by the same factor.
- To be double sure I switched the application over to the Unix Domain Socket and there the measurement was the same as the old results (no slow down).

**Looks like something in the kernel or network drivers dealing specifically with TCP/IP has gotten broken after the recent update.**

Is there a quick fix to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading from Linux kernel 4.15.0-36-generic to 4.15.0-34-generic resolved the issue for me. As originally suspected, something specifically dealing with the TCP/IP broke after the upgrade.

To downgrade, I pressed the ESC key repeatedly after the reboot to enter the Grub menu and selected the specific kernel (not the recovery mode) from the "Advanced options".